# How to remove reflection from image with with image-processing

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, filter, filtering

I'm looking for the right filter to remove reflection.
In my specific case, I want to use it on a whiteboard, for example:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUcN7.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyewi.png)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector might be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

dilation is a very simple (while not perfect) way to do that:

```
im = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('board.png')));
imd = imdilate(im,strel('diamond',1));
res = im - imd;
res = res - min(res(:)); res = res./max(res);
imshow(res)
```

[image]
you may also apply some thresholding afterwards.